# How do I emulate a keystroke in DOS programatically (in C/C++)?

Tags: c++, c, dos, keystroke, emulation

First off, I'm talking about DOS, and not Windows's command-line application.

I wish to write a procedure that would send a keystroke to the currently running process.
My goal is to use this procedure in an ISR (interrupt handler).

In other words, this is what I want to happen:

- DOS boots up.
- I run a TSR which registers my procedure as an ISR for some interrupt (not the keyboard interrupt, but for now let's assume that it is).
- I run another program, which becomes the currently running process.
- The aforementioned interrupt occurs.
- My procedure jumps in and emulates a keystroke, which, in fact, never really happened.
- The currently running process receives this keystroke as though the emulated key was actually pressed.

I found several sources with different examples, but I couldn't really get anything to work for me.

I don't know if it's of any relevance, but what I'm using at the moment to test all this includes FreeDOS running on a VirtualBox machine, and DJGPP for compiling and running the code (it uses the GNU compiler, I believe).

Any and all assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I haven't worked with DOS for a long time, but you'll probably find the core of an answer in Ralf Browns Interrupt List (http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm). Ray Duncans "Advanced MS-DOS Programming" is also an obvious suggestion, but if you have a copy you've presumably already checked it.

Comment: Look for close reason "Asked twenty years too late"...

Comment: Thinking about it, there's probably a reason why any method may be unreliable. Some DOS software probably bypasses the O/S calls, and accesses the keyboard interface in naughty ways, so that sending fake keys through DOS and/or BIOS interrupts may not have an effect.

Comment: Indeed, this question has no answer unless you're willing to virtualize the whole machine (which is probably doable considering anything for DOS only expects ~33 MHz, at most, anyway...)

Comment: What in the world is the application of a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC you have to use a BIOS call INT 16h, FUNC 05H ...? or write directly to 0040:001E (or was it 001C)... a google search turns up a couple threads about the topic...

http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-asm-x86/254441-re-how-write-char-keyboard-buffer.html

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try.
Might take a while, though.

Thanks.